# TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable [Pygame module]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have been designing a game recently as I'm starting a course at school
and thought it would be helpful to get ahead.

I encountered the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Dungeon Crawler 2.1\Main.py", line 100, in <module>
    town()    
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Dungeon Crawler 2.1\Main.py", line 85, in town
    houseSpr1(0,250)
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable
```

While executing this code.

```
def town ():
    global outTown
    while not outTown:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                            print (event)
                            mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                            mx = mx + my
                            if 375 <= mx <= 448:
                                    outTown = True
                                    print ("OK!")
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            pygame.quit()
                            quit()

            houseSpr1 = pygame.image.load ('houseD.png') # default house img
            houseSpr1(0,250)
            gameDisplay.fill(green) # background
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,grey,(0,400,1280,50)) # main path
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,grey,(200,125,50,280)) # branch path
            player(x,y)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)

def houseSpr1(a,b):
    gameDisplay.blit(houseSpr1, (0,250))

def house1():
    global outHouse
    while not outHouse:
            gameDisplay.fill(black)
town()
houseSpr1()
gameIntro()
house1()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I understand this code may be inefficient in some ways, and I would be happy to know how I can improve it as well if you wish to provide insight in that light.

---

Any help with this error would be appreciated. And yes, I have read the rest of the questions before mine and I saw it was mostly down to typographical errors, but I can not see any of those here.

Comment: Please include the **full traceback** of the exception, not just the exception line itself.

Comment: Why are you assigning a local name `houseSpr1`? You masked the global function `houseSpr1` you defined. Functions do not live in a separate namespace, you can't use the same name for multiple things.

Comment: I have no idea what masked means. I have updated the entry to show the full error. @MartijnPieters

Comment: You reused the same name as a local variable; all references to `houseSpr1` in the function `town()` refer to that local name. The global name `houseSpr1`, the function you defined, is no longer accessible inside the `town()` function.

Comment: So when you write `houseSpr1(..)`, you added the `(..)` call expression to the `houseSpr1` object you created on the line before it. Use a different name for the function or the image you loaded.

Comment: I'm afraid that does not solve the problem. I have changed the name of both the image definition, the use below it and the functions' name, and it still comes up with the exact same error, same line and everything.

Comment: Does the traceback show the changed names? If not, you are not running your new code.

Answer (score 2):

You used the name `houseSpr1` for two things:

- A global function, `def houseSpr1(a,b): ...`
- A local variable for an image you load: `houseSpr1 = pygame.image.load ('houseD.png')`.

The two names are **not independent**. Functions are just another type of object in Python, and they are just stored like any other variable.

The moment you use the expression `houseSpr1(0,250)`, Python sees this as:

1. Load the object named `houseSpr1`
2. Take the results from `0` and `250` (two integer objects)
3. Call the object loaded in step 1, passing in the results of step 2.

Because you assigned something to the name `houseSpr1` in your `town()` function, it is *that object*, the image loaded, that Python tries to call. PyGame uses an object type named `Surface` to load images, and the error tells you you tried to call that object, but that object doesn't support being called.

The solution is to not use the same name:

```
houseSpr1Image = pygame.image.load('houseD.png')
houseSpr1(0, 250)
```

You'll have to adjust your `houseSpr1` function too:

```
def houseSpr1(a,b):
    gameDisplay.blit(houseSpr1Image, (0,250))
```

You still have other problems here; `houseSpr1Image` is not a global, so the `houseSpr1()`  function won't find it, giving you a `NameError` exception. You are also ignoring the `a` and `b` arguments to the function, hardcoding the `0,250` there. You'll have to solve those issues to for the code to work. Perhaps you can take a 3rd parameter, `image`:

```
def houseSpr1(image, a, b):
    gameDisplay.blit(image, (a, b))
```

and pass in the image surface:

```
houseSpr1Image = pygame.image.load('houseD.png')
houseSpr1(houseSpr1Image, 0, 250)
```

Comment: Okay, I probably should've mentioned this first, but I had forgotten to mention the fact that I tried to assign the co-ordinates to the variables a and b, and then gave up and just inputted them directly. Due to the fact that you included a and b in this answer and that they are not easily substituted, how would I go about doing this? Could you please edit your answer accordingly, and then I will be able to flag it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I am asking for a way to change the a's and b's you put in most of the arguments in the code and swap them out with integers which will be used as the co-ordinates for the object onscreen.

Comment: @Jake: just remove the `a` and `b` arguments then.

Comment: Nope. It claims that it is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Jake: I can't see how you are removing them. If you are still this inexperienced with Python, I suggest you [work through the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: I'm literally just removing the a and b and then replacing them with the values, and yes, I am using commas. Then it highlights the first number in red and says "Invalid syntax". I never used the tutorial for python, I decided to gather bits of information along the way, that way, it is less intimidating.

Comment: @Jake: are you replacing `a` and `b` in the *function definition* too? Those are parameter definitions. You'd *remove* `a` and `b` from there, not replace them with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Martijn Pieters has already explained thoroughly why your code doesn't work. Here's a working, simplified version of your program to show you how it should look like.

Actually, the `blit_houseSpr1` function is not necessary, since you could as well call `gameDisplay.blit(houseSpr1, (80, 250))` in the main loop, but I just wanted to demonstrate how you can use a function and pass some arguments to it.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

green = pygame.Color('green4')
grey = pygame.Color('grey50')
# Load the images once, because loading them from the hard disk is slow.
# And use the convert or convert_alpha methods to improve the performance.
houseSpr1 = pygame.image.load('houseD.png').convert()


def town():
    outTown = False
    while not outTown:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                mx = mx + my
                if 375 <= mx <= 448:
                    outTown = True
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                outTown = True

        gameDisplay.fill(green) # background
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,grey,(0,400,1280,50)) # main path
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,grey,(200,125,50,280)) # branch path
        # Pass the image and the coordinates to the function.
        blit_houseSpr1(houseSpr1, 80, 250)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


def blit_houseSpr1(image, a, b):
    # Now use the passed image and coordinates.
    gameDisplay.blit(image, (a, b))


town()
pygame.quit()
```